# Encountering "Fatal error: Index fell out of range" error when random number is generated

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I'm trying to create a bingo number generator app, however after generating numbers "Fatal error: Index fell out of range" was encountered randomly on line "let letter = prefixes[bingoBall/15]".

```
var numbersSeen = Set<Int>()
var prefixes = ["B-", "I-", "N-", "G-", "O-"]

func randomNumber() -> Int {

    var nextNum : Int
    repeat {
        nextNum = Int.random(in: 1...75)

        if !numbersSeen.contains(nextNum) {
            numbersSeen.insert(nextNum)
            return Int(nextNum)
        }

    } while true
}

func randomBall() {
    let bingoBall = randomNumber()
    let letter = prefixes[bingoBall/15]
    lblNumber.text = "\(letter)\(bingoBall)"

    lblNumCalled.text = String(numbersSeen.count) + " numbers called."
    lblNumRemain.text = String(75 - numbersSeen.count) + " numbers remaining."

    if lblNumPrev.text != "" {
        lblNumPrev.text = lblNumPrev.text!+", "+lblNumber.text!
    }else{
        lblNumPrev.text = lblNumber.text!
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indices start at **zero,** not at one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution to this while still generating bingo numbers between 1 and 75 is to subtract one before doing the division when accessing the letter array

```
let letter = prefixes[(bingoBall - 1)/15]
```

This means we have numbers in the range 0-74 which when divided by 15 creates numbers in the range 0-4 which is a valid range for an array of size 5

Answer (score 1):

Array Indices Start from Zero, Dividing by 15 or arbitrary number could generate an index position which is not available thus Index Out of Bounds exception.
A possible solution which gives you the **freedom to generate a random number from any given range**:

```
let letter = prefixes[bingoBall % numbersSeen.count]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the issue:**

Since the **`array` indices start from 0**, so the indices of `prefixes` `array` will vary from `0...4`.

And the `range` that you're using for generating `randomNumber` is from `1...75`.

So the `bingoBall/15` will give `5` when `bingoBall = 75`.

Now, accessing `prefixes[5]` will result in **`Index Out of Bounds exception`**.

**Solution:**

**1.** Change the `range` of generating the `randomNumber`, i.e.

```
nextNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
```

**2.** Change the division factor such that it result in a value `<=4`, example,

```
let letter = prefixes[bingoBall/18]
```